# How can i connect 4 stepper motors and 3 sensors to an Anduino?

Tags: arduino-mega

I have an Arduino AT MEGA 2560 circuit. I want to buy 1 Nema-17 bipolar stepper motors, 3 M49SP-2K stepper motors, 3 KY-032 sensors to do my project but i dont know how to connect them to my Arduino.
Is there any Arduino shield for my purpose? Can I use Ramps 1.4 Arduino shield?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Ramps V1.6, it is what I use. It plugs onto the AT Mega board.

https://reprap.org/wiki/RAMPS_1.6

The 1.6 has a few improvements. I like the solder in power connectors rather than the plug in ones. More reliable.

Because I already had the AT Mega board I decided to try the ramps. There are better boards now, with 32 bit processors. But as a starting point the Ramps combo is the simplest to get going and it does the job.

Other boards may work out a little better, but the firmware is a bigger issue. Still in development.